# Flutter override a Class in a package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub

I am currently working on two Flutter apps that share about 90% of their functionality. Because of this, I have built most of the code as a library, and then have the two projects set up to import that library. I can then plug in two different CMS instances, and different Firebase services ... super-efficient.

The problem I have is that my library code has certain references that I would need to override in my projects to allow for bespoke menu items, theme settings etc.

A good example is a `MenuItem` enum that is used throughout my library code for navigation and routing etc. It builds the entire app structure off a list of these `MenuItem` types. I need to define a `MenuItem` enum for both of my projects, but the error I get is a conflict between the project and the library.

```
{MenuItem menuItem}
The argument type 'MenuItem (where MenuItem is defined in /Users/xx/Documents/dev/xx Creative/dev/AR_Trails_app/ar_trails_app/lib/utils/menu_items.dart)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'MenuItem (where MenuItem is defined in /Users/xx/Documents/dev/xx Creative/dev/AR_Trails_Lib/weald_ar_trails/lib/utils/menu_items.dart)'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
menu_items.dart(7, 6): MenuItem is defined in /Users/xx/Documents/dev/xx Creative/dev/AR_Trails_app/ar_trails_app/lib/utils/menu_items.dart
menu_items.dart(8, 6): MenuItem is defined in /Users/xx/Documents/dev/xx Creative/dev/AR_Trails_Lib/weald_ar_trails/lib/utils/menu_items.dart
```

I know that there is an option to use `dependency_overrides` in `Dart` but this is for overriding the entire library I think: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#dependency-overrides

How can I do this but for just one file? Or maybe two or three?

UPDATE:

To be clear on the use-case here: my file `menu_items.dart` is in the library package, and it is used throughout to build the navigation and drawer etc. But it is *only* used in the library. What I need to do is override that file in each project so that the reference the library uses is the project's local version and NOT the one that is being referenced in the library. I thought that if I used as a path reference to the file like  `../../utils/menu_items`, and mirrored that in my project, it might use the local project version. It doesn't.

Comment: So you want MenuItem to be customised for different projects right? In simple term what you need is not exactly override but the thing you want is first extend with the library one and provide that MenuItem from package. If you share what exactly are you trying from that i can give more specific answer.

Comment: It's not that I want to extend MenuItem to override properties in my project. MenuItem is only used in my shared library. But when the library is used inside of my project I would like it to use the projects version of MenuItem and not the one it is referencing in the package.

Comment: Edited the post to hopefully explain the use-case in more detail

Comment: The other thing I could do is to provide a `Config` and pass all the custom stuff through some public interface. I would need to do quite a bit of refactoring though.

Comment: Provide from outside, kind of provider? write provider and pass data for default in shared logic else on own app class add your configurations.

Comment: Yea, I think I will need to pass everything in through some kind of config. The main areas to customise is the theme data, the routing, and the navigation items. The two projects are pretty much identical so I was hoping to minimise the duplication and config. Thought there may be some way to tell the library to use the project classes instead of its own. Thanks.